# Windows11 で位置情報の取得ができない

Tags: c#, windows, gps

現在 PC の位置情報を取得するソフトウェアを作成しています。
位置情報の取得は `System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinateWatcher` を使用して取得しています。
具体的には C# で以下のようなコードを書き、 .NET Framework 4.8 で実行しています。

下記コードは、 Windows10 ではたまに取得できないことはあるものの、問題無く動作しています。
これを Windows11 で動作させると `TryStart()` は `ture` を返してくるのですが、 `position.Location.IsUnknown` に `true` が設定され、現在地が取得できません。 1 秒間隔で何度も実行するようにしても、 1 回も取得できない状況です。

Windows11 では `GeoCoordinateWatcher()` を使って位置情報を取得することはできないのでしょうか？もしくは何か準備が必要なのでしょうか？
(Windows 側の設定のプライバシーの位置情報は全て "ON" に設定しています)

何かご存知でしたらご教示いただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
...

using ( var watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher() )
{
    bool b = watcher.TryStart(false, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
    buf = $"TryStart の戻り値={b}\r\n";

    var position = watcher.Position;
    if ( !position.Location.IsUnknown )
    {
        buf += $"Timestamp={position.Timestamp}\r\nLatitude={position.Location.Latitude}\r\nLongitude={position.Location.Longitude}\r\n";
    }
    else
    {
        buf += "取得できませんでした。\r\n";
    }
}
...
```

Comment: タイムアウト値を延ばしてみるとか、イベントサブスクライブ方式に切り替えてみるとか、試してみてはどうでしょう？ [GeoCoordinateWatcher クラス](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher?view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=net-6.0)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
タイムアウト値を伸ばしてみましたが同じ状況でした。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

watcher.Position を取得する時点では Status がまだ NoData なので位置情報が取得できないのでは？

であれば、Status が Ready になるまで待ってみてはいかがですか？

どのようにするかの例は以下の記事の下の方の回答を見てください。

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/2fbc243d-53ce-49bf-b79a-ebce13adf3d6/deleted?forum=netfxgeneralja

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
Status が Ready になるまで待ったら取得することができました。しばらく悩んでいたので大変助かりました。

Answer (score 0):

Status が Ready になるまで待ったら取得できました。具体的には以下の様にすれば Windows11 でも取得することができました。

```
...

using ( var watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher() )
{
    bool b = watcher.TryStart(false, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
    buf = $"TryStart の戻り値={b}\r\n";

    // vvv 追加
    while ( watcher.Status != GeoPositionStatus.Ready )
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    // ^^^ 追加

    var position = watcher.Position;
    if ( !position.Location.IsUnknown )
    {
        buf += $"Timestamp={position.Timestamp}\r\nLatitude={position.Location.Latitude}\r\nLongitude={position.Location.Longitude}\r\n";
    }
    else
    {
        buf += "取得できませんでした。\r\n";
    }
}

...
```

Comment: 紹介した記事のように geoWatcher.Permission != GeoPositionPermission.Denied も while の条件に入れないと、位置情報の取得が有効になってない場合、無限ループに陥るので注意してください。

Comment: 返信遅くなり申し訳ございません。 while 条件の件承知いたしました。追加の情報ありがとうございました。